# What is the best way to position a pie chart in order to keep good website design?

Tags: web, graphics, graph, pie-chart

I have a webpage that I am working on and am new to proper web design. As a beginner of course I wanted to center everything, but then I picked up a book to teach me better design principles. So, here is the deal:

On my webpage, all of my other elements are left-aligned to give a bold unquestionable organization to all of the elements on the page and of course all "like" elements are grouped together and formatted to give the appropriate contrast. The only problem to this is I have a pie chart that has a title and 3 keys beneath it and I don't know how to position it to make it match everything else. I was given advice to place the chart, title, and keys into a separate container and center them within the container and then left align the container. But that still didn't look right to me.

What is the best way to deal with this pie chart??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice you received was good, having each part in it's own div will give you more control over how they're placed in relation to each other. All these should be placed inside another div, which you can use to align the group. If your site is not concerned about liquid or responsive layout, you can use CSS to give the group div a precise location. Code should look something like this:

```
HTML:
   <div id="all">
      <div id="chart-title">
         <img src="/img/chart-title.jpg"
      </div>

      <div id="chart">
         <img src="/img/chart.jpg></img>
      </div>

      <div id="chart-key">
         <img src="/img/chart-key.jpg"></img>
      </div>
   </div>

CSS:
   #chart-title {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }

   #chart-key {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }

   #chart {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }

   #all {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-left: 40px;
      margin-top: 40px;
   }
```

This will give each element of the chart it's own section, which can be resized as needed (replace 100% with a px value) and then put each of those into a group container called "all", which you can use to position the group. If the information is all left-aligned, you might want the accompanying chart off to the right. 'margin-left' and 'margin-top' set the distance this div will be from the ones next to it. this will help you get position where you want it. So in the example code I gave, it will place the group 40 pixels to the right of the div directly before it, and 40 pixels below any div above it. Try playing with these values until you find something that looks good. Layout is not an exact science, it's more about what feels right to you. Someone might be able to give you some layout advice if you gave us a screenshot of what you have so far, or a link to the site in question. Hopefully this gave you some direction.

Comment: I wish I could give you a screen shot, but since I am new I do not have enough "cred" to post images to my questions. It's really tying my hands behind my back here. :/ 
Look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm
The second pie chart is basically what I have. 

Yes, programmatically speaking that makes a lot of sense. Right now I am using Balsamiq and a good eye. Any non-code advice since I haven't reached that stage yet?

Comment: I hear you on the newbie cred issue- I'm facing similar. I don't have any experience with Balsamiq, so I can't give you any "how-to" instruction about that, but it seems like you're just having layout/design issues. From a design standpoint, and what I gathered from your question, a website that is entirely aligned left is usually very boring. You might want to consider balancing things out a little, by adding some elements to the right side. [THIS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/strucrealistic-boxes.png) is a good example, content on the left, secondary info right

Comment: Yeah, Well I appreciate the help, that is a really good starting point for me! I would upvote your answer to help out your cred but I don't have enough cred to even upvote an answer on my own question. :( Silly Rules. Thank you!

Comment: haha no problem, glad it was helpful. Good luck with the project!